# Displaying JSON containing MySQL table data using jQuery $.ajax method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have written the following a PHP code to retrieve multiple rows from MySQL database and subsequently convert it to JSON. This PHP file is named **sql_json.php** and is called via jQuery using method $.ajax. The jQuery code is in the file **jquery_fetch.js** . Finally I want to display it in the HTML file **json_search_user.html**. Retrieval from MySQL is working correctly. But the jQuery code is not working and hence it is unable to display the encoded JSON.

**PHP Code:(sql_json.php)**

```
   <?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php_revision/dbase.php'); //dbase.php contains dtabase parameters like servername, username,password etc.

$conn=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$db_name) or die('Connection to database failed');

if($conn){

$sql="SELECT FNAME,LNAME,DEPT,MOBILE_NO FROM USER WHERE ROLE=?" ;

$stmt=mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$role);

$role=$_POST['role'];

if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    $json= array();

    $data_array=array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $data_array['FNAME']=$row['FNAME'];
        $data_array['LNAME']=$row['LNAME'];
        $data_array['DEPT']=$row['DEPT'];
        $data_array['MOBILE_NO']=$row['MOBILE_NO'];

        array_push($json,$data_array); 

    }
    echo  json_encode($json);
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}   
else{

 echo json_encode({"Status" : "No results found"});
 }
 ?>
```

**jQuery Code:(jquery_fetch.js)**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {


  $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e){

  var role= $('#role').val();

  $.ajax({

      url:"sql_json.php",

      type: "POST",

      dataType: "JSON",

      data:{role : role} ,

      success: function(data){

          var response= JSON.parse(data);

          var genHtml='<table><tbody>';

          for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
          {

             genHtml += '<tr><td>' + response[i].FNAME + '' + response[i].LNAME + '</td><td>' + response[i].DEPT + '</td><td>' + response[i].MOBILE_NO + '</td></tr>';

          }

          genHtml += '</tbody></table>';

          $('#search_result').html(genHtml); 

      }

    });

    });   

    });
```

**HTML File (json_search_user.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Search User </title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256- FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_fetch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="sql_json.php" id="myForm">
<label for="role">Select Role :</label>
<select id="role" name="role" required>
<option disabled selected>Select</option>
<option value="Author">Author</option>
<option value="Publisher">Publisher</option>
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">

<div id="search_result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can open your developer console in browser and look if any errors are printed out.

Answer (score 2):

You have an action in your form, when you click submit, it will open the file 'sql_json.php' so your js code will not render the html to the page. you need to prevent the default behavior of form submit. by adding e.preventDefault() in your javascript function.